# Calculate quality estimates for distribution of real data

Tags: r, distributions, quality-control

Imagine I have measured heights of humans (in cm) and show the data in a histogram:

```
# Generate sample data
sampleSize = 100000
sampleData = round(rnorm(n = sampleSize, mean = 175, sd = 14))

# Draw histogram of sample
h = hist(sampleData, breaks = max(sampleData) - min(sampleData), plot=T)
```

Now I want to know how realistic each size in the distribution is. For example I found a human with the size of 100cm and I want to know if this individual is overrepresented in my sample. **I want to give a measure for the uncertainty for each height class.** How can I do that?

My first idea was to bootstrap the measured data, calculate the standard deviation for each class among the bootstrapped samples and give a relative standard-deviation (scaled by 1000) for each class.

```
######################################################################
# Calculate the standard Deviation for each sampled size of a bootstrap measurement
cycles = 100000

# initialize results-matrix
result = matrix(0, nrow = length(h$counts), ncol = cycles)

# sample original data
for (i in 1:cycles) {
    tmp = hist(sample(sampleData, replace = T, size = sampleSize), breaks = h$breaks, plot=F)
    result[,i] = tmp$counts
    print(paste("cycle:", i))
}

# calculate standard deviations
for (i in 1:length(h$counts)) {
    h$sdboot[i] = sd(result[i,])
}

######################################################################
pdf("boot.pdf")
    # Plotting
    #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    plot(h)
    # Bootstrap: standarddeviations
    polygon(x=c(rev(h$mids), h$mids), y= c(rev(h$counts + h$sdboot), h$counts - h$sdboot), col="#ff000022")

    #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    plot(h)
    # Bootstrap: standarddeviations
    polygon(
        x=c(rev(h$mids), h$mids),
        y= c(rev(h$counts + 1000 * (h$sdboot / h$counts)), h$counts - 1000 * (h$sdboot / h$counts)),
        col="#00ff0022"
    )

    #+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    plot(x=h$mids, y=h$sdboot/h$counts)

dev.off()
```

The resulting graphs (2 and 3) show the increasing uncertainty with lower numbers of counts in the class, but I'm not sure how informative that is. It does not really answer the question "**How likely is it, that you miss members of a certain height class in a measurement with the same sampleSize?**" or "**How likely is it, that the value is of the measured size just by chance**"

One problem might be, that I do not have a model for my real data (For human height one could assume a normal distribution).

Is it somehow possible to give a measure for the uncertainty of my real data?

Comment: Not quite sure if I am in the right direction, however, maybe this helps. For your first question, would **entropy** help? Assuming you have a normal distribution under which the heights must be (law of large samples helps you with this assumption), you can estimate the probability of a particular height and from your sample, you could estimate the probability from your real data and then compute the [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory))?